# How to insert unique value from other table while copying data in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-migration

I am migrating data from old database to new database.
old database has some duplicate values (didn't have unique constraint) but new database have unique constraint. so I want only one row while migrating to new.

`phoneNumber` is field which have `unique constraint` in `new database` but did not have `unique constraint` in `old database`.

getting error  `Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '' for key 'phoneNumber'`

```
INSERT INTO
    newdb.user (
        id,
        email,
        password,
        firstName,
        lastName,
        phoneNumber,
        role,
        createdOn
    )
SELECT
    u.id,
    IF(u.email IS NULL, "NA", u.email),
    IF(u.password IS NULL, "NA", u.password),
    IF(u.firstName IS NULL, "NA", u.firstName),
    IF(u.lastName IS NULL, "NA", u.lastName),
    IF(ud.phoneNumber IS NULL, " ", ud.phoneNumber),
    IF(u.roleId = 1, 'ADMIN', 'USER'),
    u.createdAt
FROM
    olddb.users u
    INNER JOIN olddb.userdetails ud ON ud.userId = u.id;
```

Comment: Use `INSERT IGNORE` - it will skip rows which causes duplicate violations.

Comment: *Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '' for key 'phoneNumber'* This means that the value not is absent but is empty string, not that it is present but duplicated. If you'll use INSERT IGNORE then you'll loose needed rows. I recommend you to replace empty value with NULL (in your case - store NULL values, do not replace) - they are not treated as duplicates. If you have defined the columns as NOT NULL - then remove this restrictions. They must be set only when no data contains the value which is not set.

Comment: Tip of today: `COALESCE(u.email, 'NA')`.

Comment: The above query will not transfer a user without a phone number... Do LEFT JOIN, GROUP BY.